# Taking minor after/before change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $ M_n$ denote the set of $n\times n$ matrices over some field $\mathbb F$, e.g. $\mathbb Q$. For $A\in M_n$, denote $A_i^j$ the minor of $A$ after removing the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

Let $A$ be some generic matrix in $M_n$. Take $S\in SL_n$ and let $B=SAS^{-1}$. I am interested in the relationship between $A^{k}_k$ and $B_k^k$, especially their determinant.

Can I find a matrix $L\in M_{n-1}$ such that $L A_k^k L^{-1}=B_k^k$?

Is there any linear algebra trick that can address $\frac{\det A_k^k}{\det B_k^k}$?

Thanks.

Comment: If $I$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and $I_k$ denotes the matrix that is equal to $I$ except that the $k$th diagonal entry equals $0$ rather than $1$, then $A_k^k$ is closely related to the matrix $A' = I_kAI_k + I - I_k$: this matrix $A'$ has the same $(k,k)$ minor as $A$ and than an extra "neutral" row and column of all $0$s except the diagonal entry $1$. In particular, $\det A' = \det A_k^k$.

Can we relate $B' = I_kBI_k + I - I_k = I_kSAS^{-1}I_k + I - I_k$ to $SA'S^{-1} = S(I_kAI_k + I - I_k)S^{-1} = SI_kS^{-1}BSI_kS^{-1} + I - SI_kS^{-1}$?